# pt-table-sync - Resync non existing table

Tags: mysql, percona-toolkit

I created my little lab where I can try different setup/scenarios. I have four machines debootsraped/chroot and this is my current layout:

`| Master A | < ---- > | Master B |
      |

| Slave C |            | Slave D |`

Database is created with one table, replication is working.

Intention of this post it to find out if it is possible to do the following:

- I set sql_log_bin=0 and create table called sync on masterA, (to simulate inconsistent state)
- then I returned variable sql_log_bin to 1.

Normally when I try to use pt-table-sync this doesn't work (throwing error that table doesn't exists; which is noted on percona site), so I was thinking if I create identical table on slave and try to synchronize that it will work but it doesn't.

Is there a solution to sync it with pt-table-sync, to avoid backing up db on masterB and moving to masterA?

Comment: How it happens that it "doesn't work"? Any error from `pt-table-sync`? No error but not changing anything?

Comment: I was trying to execute it on slave. I can't reproduce it now, I will play with it later. Now i tried on master and it's working. `pt-table-sync --execute h=127.0.1.1 h=127.0.1.2`